# Wordpress Custom Post type roles

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type in wordpress and as admin I can do anything with this. But I want to create a role "Client" that can only add, edit and remove things of this custom post type, so he may not post a regular post, edit it or delete it and the same with pages.

These are my arguments of my custom post type

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'thumbnail'
    ),
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_portfolio',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_portfolios',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_portfolios',
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_portfolios',
        'read_post' => 'read_portfolios',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_portfolios',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_portfolio',
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false
);
```

and these is the role i have created

```
add_role("client", "Client", array(
    'read' => true, // allows this capability, dashboard
    'upload_files'=>true, //allows user to upload files
    'edit_posts' => false, // denies  user to edit their own posts
    'edit_pages' => false, // denies  user to edit pages
    'edit_others_posts' => false, // denies  user to edit others posts not just their own
    'create_posts' => false, // denies  user to create new posts
    'manage_categories' => false, // denies user to manage post categories
    'publish_posts' => false, // denies the user to publish
    'edit_themes' => false, // false denies this capability. User can’t edit your theme
    'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
    'update_plugin' => false, // User can’t update any plugins
    'update_core' => false, // user cant perform core updates
    'edit_portfolios' => true, // allows editing of the user’s own portfolio
    'edit_others_portfolios' => true, // allows the user to edit everyone else’s portfolio
    'delete_portfolios' => true, // allows to delete portfolio written by that user
    'delete_others_portfolios' => true, // allows to delete portfolio written by other users
    'publish_portfolios' => true // allows the user to publish portfolio, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
));
```

The effect now is that they can see the posts in the dashboard, but not change or click on it, can not delete and when they post a message they end up on a error screen that says they should not see this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, so for people who also have this problem.
You have to place this capabilities and set them on true

```
'delete_posts'=>'delete_portfolios',
'delete_others_posts'=>'delete_others_portfolios',
'delete_published_posts'=>'delete_published_portfolios',
'delete_private_posts'=>'delete_private_portfolios'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this programmatically but if you are don't mind using a plugin, I have used this https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/ one on several sites and its quick and easy.

I understand some people have an aversion to plugins but I have not had any issues with that one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
when I look with a plugin I think they have the correct rights to do this.
So I think I need something more in my code.